# MVC - Showing picture from another Model in my View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Im currently working on a personal project and so far everything is working quite fine but right now i have trouble showing my pictures and currently out of ideas on how to put them together.

CarModel

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Brand{ get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Range(1900,2017)]
    public int Buildyear { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }
```

PictureModel

```
    public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CarId{ get; set; }

    public string UploadedFile { get; set; }

    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

CarSearchResultViewModel

```
public class CarSearchResultViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Brand ")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type ")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int Buildyear { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }

    public Brandstof Fuel { get; set; }

    public string Extra_Information { get; set; }

    public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }


    //Either of these 2 are not necessary
    public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    public string UploadedFile { get; set; }

}
```

CarController

```
List<CarSearchResultViewModel> result = new List<CarSearchResultViewModel>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            result = (from pd in db.Cars
                      join od in db.Pictures on pd.Id equals od.CarId into odPictures                          
                      where pd.Brand == autoZVM.Brand 
                      && pd.Fuel == autoZVM.Fuel
                      && pd.Type == autoZVM.Type
                      && pd.Buildyear > autoZVM.MinBuildyear && pd.Buildyear < autoZVM.MaxBuildyear 
                      && pd.Price > autoZVM.MinPrice && pd.Price < autoZVM.MaxPrice 
                      select new CarSearchResultViewModel
                      {
                          Brand= pd.Brand,
                          Type = pd.Type,
                          Fuel = pd.Fuel ,
                          Buildyear = pd.Buildyear,
                          Pictures = odPictures.ToList(),                           
                          Price= pd.Price,
                          Extra_Information = pd.Extra_Information

                      }).ToList();
        }
        return View("Result", result);
```

ResultView

```
@model IEnumerable<The_Scrubberij.Models.AutoZoekResultaatViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Result";
}

<h2>Result</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>


<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Brand) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)

                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">

                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Buildyear)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Extra_Information)   -  <img src="@Url.Content(Model.UploadedFile)"></img>


                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

> IEnumerable ' does not contain a definition for 'UploadedFile' and no extension method 'UploadedFile' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable ' could be found

here is the table relationship with a simple SQL query
[image]

I have no idea how to link these two things together hints would be appreciated

My thanks, Leroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have an `<img>` element with the source set to the path of the file, assuming the stored paths are accessible from the client exactly as they are. Or use Url.Content instead of the raw value in the property.

`<img src="@Url.Content(Model.UploadedFile)"></img>`

Edit: oh hang on I missed the fact that you don't have a relationship between car and picture. Seeing as a car can have multiple pictures, you need a list of Pictures on the CarSearchResultViewModel and you need to populate it with the list of pictures returned by the join. Probably something like:

```
        result = (from pd in db.Cars
                  join od in db.Pictures on pd.Id equals od.CarId
                  where ...
                  select new CarSearchResultViewModel
                  {
                      Brand= pd.Brand,
                      ...,
                      Pictures = od.ToList()
                  }).ToList();
```

I didn't test this since I don't want to set up a full project but something like it.

Comment: So i  the add a property public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; } in my CarSearchResultviewModel and in my LINQ query i add Pictures = od.ToList()

 If i try this im getting an error with "  'Picture' does not contain ToList"

Comment: Well I haven't actually tried it so you may have to fiddle with it a little. The alternative is (assuming this is Entity Framework we're talking about) to make the Picture an associated entity to Car, that way you'd have the list of pictures on every car and you can tell EF to Include() pictures when retrieving the cars, and you no longer have to think of how to do the join yourself. You then simply get the cars and automatically have every car's pictures as well.

Comment: Right a join operator simply creates a pair of Car and Picture, it doesn't automatically turn od into a list of pictures. You need to do a group join: join od in db.Pictures on pd.Id equals od.CarId *into odPictures*, then Pictures = odPictures.ToList()

Comment: Seems like im getting somewhere now i have to find out whats wrong with the <img src="@Url.Content(Model.UploadedFile)"></img> . I have edited my code to show the eror

Comment: In that context I think the Model is the list of Cars, not each Picture; I used Model in my example without carefully examining your code. You would need to iterate over the pictures of each item first, so something like @foreach (var p in item.Pictures) { <img src="@Url.Content(p.UploadedFile)"></img> }

Answer (score 0):

You Can Solve the problem is simple,you have use  `<img>` src Attribute

You have the Edit controller

```
result = (from pd in db.Cars
                  join od in db.Pictures on pd.Id equals od.CarId
                  where pd.Brand == autoZVM.Brand 
                  && pd.Fuel == autoZVM.Fuel
                  && pd.Type == autoZVM.Type
                  && pd.Buildyear > autoZVM.MinBuildyear && pd.Buildyear < autoZVM.MaxBuildyear 
                  && pd.Price > autoZVM.MinPrice && pd.Price < autoZVM.MaxPrice 
                  select new CarSearchResultViewModel
                  {
                      Brand= pd.Brand,
                      Type = pd.Type,
                      Fuel = pd.Fuel ,
                      Buildyear = pd.Buildyear ,                           
                      Price= pd.Price,
                      Extra_Information = pd.Extra_Information,
                      Pictures=Od.UploadedFile
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

With all the help of the other awnsers i have finally got my solution hereby for what i have done

In my CarSearchResultViewmodel i have added a list of Pictures

```
    public class AutoZoekResultaatViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Brand ")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Picture> Pictures{ get; set; }
}
```

After that i edited my my LINQ Query with the help of Alex Praven

```
from pd in db.Cars
join od in db.Pictures on pd.Id equals od.CarId into odPictures
where pd.Brand == autoZVM.Brand
...

select new CarSearchResultviewModel
{
  Brand = pd.Brand,
  Pictures = odPictures.ToList(),
}).ToList();
```

and in my Result.cshtml

```
 @foreach (var Picture in item.Pictures)
 {
  <img src="/pictures/@Url.Content(foto.UploadedFile)"></img>
 }
```

Comment: For some reason everybody misspells my name, I should just change it :P